# why we should use "null" in dialog boxes?

Tags: java, dialog, jgrasp

I want to know why we should write "null" in dialog boxes ?

```
str= JOptioPane.showMessageDialog(
                                 parentComponent(null), // <--
                                 messageStringExpression,
                                 boxTitleString,
                                 meeageType);
```

and when we have to write it ?
can I write something else ?

thanks all

Comment: Here is the API doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why we should write "null" in dialog boxes ?

If the parentComponent is `null` (aka `parentComponent(null)`), then the JDialog depends on no visible window, and it's placed in a look-and-feel-dependent position such as the center of the screen.

> can I write something else

Sure, you can add there any component you want like JButton, ....

Some example:

```
private JButton btn_Save;

btn_Save = new JButton(save);
        btn_Save.setText("Save Configuration");
        btn_Save.setBounds(20, 459, 290, 25);
        btn_Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == btn_Save) {
                    if(saveData()){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn_Save, "Event Configuration saved successfully!");
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn_Save, "Failed to save Event Configuration!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this case against `null`, The dialog centered on button `btn_Save`

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentComponent(null),message);
```

Then dialog centered on the `desktop`.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(someComponent,message);
```

Then dialog centered on the `someComponent`